# Height and Padding CSS Properties Not Working On Search Input Element

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a simple search form on a Wordpress site and for some reason on the search input element, the `height` and `padding` CSS properties aren't working. I've no idea why?

The code is below or you can see it on CodePen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/NWqBEXq

Any help much appreciated. It's driving me a bit insane.

SCREENSHOT - The search element should be 2rem height with 2rem of padding.

[image]

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#s{
  width: 20rem; 
  height: 2rem; /* not working */
  padding: 2rem; /* not working */
}
```

```html
<div id="form-wrap">
  <form id="site-search-form">
    <div id="site-search-input-wrap">
      <input id="s" name="s" type="search" placeholder="Enter your search">
      <input class="site-search-submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is the search box showing with padding and height applied? It isn't when I look at the code snippet above

Comment: it's for me, show us a screenshot of what you see and maybe add more detail about the browser you are using

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've added a screen shot to the original question

Comment: add more detail about your browser because I don't see what you are showing

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm on the latest version of Chrome (79 I think).

Comment: I am also on chrome, maybe you are showing the result of your site (where there is probably more CSS) and no the one on the snippet here?

Comment: No, that screenshot if from the snippet on this question.

Comment: @TheChewy might help to change the type to text and take a screenshot of that for comparison.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  I found the solution - you have to add a border property otherwise it will always give the default border regardless, which restricts the visual height. Will add as an answer.

Comment: @dgknca Can I ask why this question has been closed? It is a genuine question. After a lot of research I discovered that search input form elements need to have a border CSS property added for the height and padding properties to work (this is not the case with other form elements), yet it's been closed due to being "a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced"...which is nonsense. It's a genuine problem with a genuine solution.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Apologies - will delete it. Will re-post with the user the OP mentions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't really let you mess with `input type="search"` CSS-Tricks has a pretty [good overview](https://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/).

If styling is important, I'd either find a component or change to `input type="text"` and replicate other desired search functionality (like suggest list or history) with Javascript.

Chances are a simple text search will work just fine as a text input.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this - you need to add a `border` CSS property to a `search` input element otherwise the default border will remain and thus restrict the visual height of the element. For example adding `border: 1px solid` fixes the issue.